# How to do proper search as filter not working

Tags: swift4.2

I used:
var userArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

view did load :

```
searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

Then:

```
extension ChatListController : UITextFieldDelegate{

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

        userArray = userArray.filter { ($0 ["name"] as! String).range(of: textField.text!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }

        print("Filter userArray : ",userArray)
        self.userTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Throws error: @ $0

> error: Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

```
var userArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

extension ChatListController : UITextFieldDelegate{

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

        userArray = userArray.filter { ($0 ["name"] as! String).range(of: textField.text!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }

        print("Filter userArray : ",userArray)
        self.userTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

Comment: user array is:
        userArray ::  (
                {
                “name” = raj;
                “number” = 5050214521;
            },
                {
                 “name” = ramesh;
                “number” = 410145235;  
          },
          {
                 “name” = suresh;
                “number” = 7415823691;  
          }
        )

Comment: Solved by using this:

let array = userArray.filter({ (theState) -> Bool in
            return ((theState["name"] as! String).localizedLowercase.contains(textField.text!))
        })

Answer (score 0):

@raj use this code

```
userArray = userArray.filter({($0["name"] as? 
 String)!.contains(searchString.lowercased())
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations along with your code, so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23322536)